# Python parsing file dies at 108th file... dict full?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have this function that parses a few hundred large csv files and combined the lines into a dictionary:

```
for f in file_list:
    with open(os.path.join(path, f)) as list:
        for line in list:
            data = line.split(',')
            if data[1]:
                tup = (data[0], data[1])
                try:
                    master_dict[tup][0] += int(data[2])
                    master_dict[tup][1] += int(data[3])
                except KeyError:
                    master_dict[tup] = [int(data[2]), int(data[3])]
                print len(master_dict) # DEBUG LINE
```

The csvs are 5-10k lines each and they are in this format:

```
string1,string2,12345,12345
```

The 12345 numbers are large numbers (the first can be in the billions, the second is in the <100000)

The process seems to just die after some time (on the 108th file, randomly) (running on CentOS) and the only thing that is returned is:

```
Killed
```

Oddly, the 108th file is where it dies regardless of which file it is (its not always the same file).

I added a line that prints the length of the dictionary:

```
print len(master_dict)
```

And based on the output:

```
1
2
3
...
653773
653774
653775
653776
653777
653778
653778
Killed
```

I am thinking that maybe the dictionary gets full and dies? The dictionary length prints out the same on the last run, and then dies.

**Is there a max length for dictionaries? Why does the process die?**

My system memory:

Mem:        604480

Comment: Examine your system logs. OOM killer in action?

Comment: Sounds like an OutOfMemory error to me. Probably your system detects the process is using too much RAM and kills it.

Comment: It was the OOM killer! What can I do? dump the dict to file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are experiencing a general out-of-memory condition.  So `master_dict` is not getting full, it's just getting big.

One way around that is to use a database (any database) to store the data as you go and not a `dict`.

Comment: Thanks. I'll probably go this route. Do temp tables exist in memory? Asking so I don't encounter the same error writing to a db.

Comment: Not sure, but Postgres will be pretty smart about how it stores things -- I'm pretty sure there would by shrieks across the land if postgres daemons were being killed left and right.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem.

I used `MongoDB` instead of `Dictionary`.

Comment: I output to a file. I'm also running postgres on the box. Should I stand up mongo just to store the output then pull the output and write to a file?